# Haversine Fomula with MySQL get nearby locations

Tags: php, mysql, location, google-maps-markers, distance

I'm trying to use the haversine formula in my PHP/MySQL to get nearby locations to where I am

I'm using AJAX to get only nearby markers on my google map.

What I know is that my query isn't returning anything.

I know that there is a location within the distance of where I'm looking.

Basically, what's wrong with my code using the haversine formula?

EDIT - Changed a ton to follow tutorial from [here](http://www.snipe.net/2008/12/ip-geolocation-radius-search-in-php/). The error is still the same.

PHP

```
$lati = 40.78405877579076;
$longi = -73.94800172194275;

class RadiusCheck
{
    var $maxLat;
    var $minLat;
    var $maxLong;
    var $minLong;

    function RadiusCheck($Latitude, $Longitude, $Miles)
    {
        global $maxLat,$minLat,$maxLong,$minLong;
        $EQUATOR_LAT_MILE = 69.172;
        $maxLat = $Latitude + $Miles / $EQUATOR_LAT_MILE;
        $minLat = $Latitude - ($maxLat - $Latitude);
        $maxLong = $Longitude + $Miles / (cos($minLat * M_PI / 180) * $EQUATOR_LAT_MILE);
        $minLong = $Longitude - ($maxLong - $Longitude);
    }

    function MaxLatitude()
    {
        return $GLOBALS["maxLat"];
    }
    function MinLatitude()
    {
        return $GLOBALS["minLat"];
    }
    function MaxLongitude()
    {
        return $GLOBALS["maxLong"];
    }
    function MinLongitude()
    {
        return $GLOBALS["minLong"];
    }
}

class DistanceCheck
{
    function DistanceCheck()
    {

    }

    function Calculate($dblLat1, $dblLong1, $dblLat2, $dblLong2)
    {
        $EARTH_RADIUS_MILES = 3963;
        $dist = 0;

        //convert degrees to radians
        $dblLat1 = $dblLat1 * M_PI / 180;
        $dblLong1 = $dblLong1 * M_PI / 180;
        $dblLat2 = $dblLat2 * M_PI / 180;
        $dblLong2 = $dblLong2 * M_PI / 180;

        if ($dblLat1 != $dblLat2 || $dblLong1 != $dblLong2)
        {
            //the two points are not the same
            $dist = sin($dblLat1) * sin($dblLat2) + cos($dblLat1) * cos($dblLat2) * cos($dblLong2 - $dblLong1);
            $dist = $EARTH_RADIUS_MILES * (-1 * atan($dist / sqrt(1 - $dist * $dist)) + M_PI / 2);
        }

        return $dist;
    }
}

// set a default number of miles to search within
$Miles = '2';

// set the user's latitude and longitude as the one to search against
$Latitude = $lati;
$Longitude = $longi;

$zcdRadius = new RadiusCheck($Latitude,$Longitude,$Miles);
$minLat = $zcdRadius->MinLatitude();
$maxLat = $zcdRadius->MaxLatitude();
$minLong = $zcdRadius->MinLongitude();
$maxLong = $zcdRadius->MaxLongitude();

$sql = "SELECT `uname`, `it`, `name`, SQRT((((69.1*(latitude-$Latitude))*(69.1*(latitude-$Latitude)))+((53*(longitude-$Longitude))*(53*(longitude-$Longitude))))) AS calc FROM stores WHERE latitude >= '$minLat' AND latitude <= '$maxLat' AND longitude >= '$minLong' AND longitude <= '$maxLong'";

$get_data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_data))
{
    // calculate the number of miles away the result is
    $zcdDistance = new DistanceCheck;
    $Distance = $zcdDistance->Calculate($Latitude, $Longitude, $row['latitude'], $row['longitude']);

    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $it = $row['it'];
    $uname = $row['uname'];

    $data["markers"][] = array
    (
        "latitude" => $lat,
        "longitude" => $lon,
        "name" => $name,
        "it" => $it,
        "uname" => $uname
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ... null
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic since the code works fine and the OP just forgot to change the table/column names

Comment: At first it wasn't the case, but it seems OP is more interested in finding working code than trying to understand what he is doing :( BTW nice tutorial, introduces class with methods to return global variables :D

Comment: I wanted to ask what was wrong with the code. I ended up changing a few things from the tut, but was still having some problems. Yes the end result was a stupid mistake, but @dev-null-dweller is right, the link i followed helped me learn about classes and global variables.

Comment: Which link helped you learn about classes? If you mean the one you posted (snipe.net) than I'm sorry, but my comment was meant to be sarcastic. Usage of class in this tutorial is wrong, meaningless and certainly you should not try to learn about classes and OOP from it.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I did mean snipe.net. Where is a better link to learn about classes and other OOP methods?

Comment: Start at the source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Im an idiot.

Code in question works perfectly. I just was using the wrong table name and column names for the `SELECT`

Hope this is useful to future people who need help.

Comment: You should accept this answer when you can.

Answer (score 5):

You have an error in your sql. You should check `$result` before passing it to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

The problem is lack of one operator or mismatched parenthesis: `cos()radians(lon)`