# How to get locations in the range of 1KM nearby current_location?

Tags: ios, sqlite, location

There is a table *location* in the database:

```
id | latitude | longitude
---| -------- | --------
1  | 45.0000  | 90.0000
...
```

so I can use SQL to query locations that I want:

```
SELECT id FROM location 
WHERE latitude BETWEEN min_latitude AND max_latitude
AND longitude BETWEEN min_longitude AND max_longitude;
```

in which min_latitude,max_latitude,min_longitude,max_longitude means 4 borders of 1KM nearby current_location.

now I want to know, how can I get min_latitude,max_latitude,min_longitude,max_longitude using current_location?

[image]

I have seen the answer of this question:[How to get the nearest area from a list of locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027558/how-to-get-the-nearest-area-from-a-list-of-locations), if there are too many *allLocations*, I dont think it is a good solution.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392784/haversine-fomula-with-mysql-get-nearby-locations?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that your desired approach with max and min lat/lon selects rows that are within a box from the current position and not within a circle as the diagram suggests.
The challenge is that the longitudinal delta in degrees is varying with latitude for a given distance. This code simplifies earth into a perfect sphere.

```
    double centerLat = 45.0;
    double centerLon = 90.0;

    double d = 1000; // desired distance in meters

    double angle = 45 * M_PI / 180; // 45 degrees in radians
    double oneDegree = 111319.9; // distance in meters from degree to degree at the equator

    double maxLat = centerLat + (d / oneDegree) * sin(angle);
    double maxLon = centerLon + (d / (oneDegree*(cos(centerLat * M_PI / 180)))) *  cos(angle);
    double minLat = centerLat - (d / oneDegree)* sin(angle);
    double minLon = centerLon - (d / (oneDegree*(cos(centerLat * M_PI / 180)))) *  cos(angle);
```

Comment: Hi, how do you get the constant `double oneDegree = 111319.9`?

Comment: I looked it up in wikipedia :-). It is what you get if you divide the circumference of the earth by 360.